# Implementing Breadth first search

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, breadth-first-search

Your friend bought you a present for the New Year, it's a puzzle! The puzzle consists of a number of
wooden rectangular pieces of varying lengths and widths and a board. The goal is to position the
wooden pieces on the board in a way such that all of the pieces will fit.

I have this program and I need help fixing my breadth first search algorithm.
Right now it is very slow and using a lot of memory. I think it is because I deep copy multiple times. The solve function is the main function and will do the heavy work.
I added a text file that has the first line as the dimensions of the puzzle and the rest of the lines are pieceID, pieceWidth and pieceLength respectively.
This is the Input File. Thank you so much.

```
10,10
1,10,1
2,1,10
3,1,5
4,3,5
5,20,2
6,1,5
7,1,5
8,2,5
```

[image]
[image]

```
import argparse, copy
import queue
import copy
import numpy as np

class PuzzleBoard():

    def __init__(self, board_length, board_width ):
        self.l = board_length
        self.w = board_width
        self.state = [[0 for _ in range(board_width)] for _ in range(board_length)]
        self.used_piece = []

    # Input: point - tuple cotaining (row_index, col_index) of point in self.state
    # Returns true if point is out of bounds; otherwise, returns false
    def __out_of_bounds(self, point):
        # TODO: Implement this function
        if(point < 0 or point > (len(self.state)) or (point > (self.state[0]))):
            return True
        return False

    # Finds the next available open space in the PuzzleBoard (looking from the top-left in row-major order)
    def __next(self):
        for i in range(len(self.state)) :
            for j in range(len(self.state[0])):
                if (self.state[i][j] == 0):
                    return (i, j)
        return False

    # Input: piece - PuzzlePiece object
    # Check if piece fits in the next available space (determined by __next method above)

    def fits(self, piece):

        position = self.__next()
        if not position:
            return False

        #TODO: Check if any part of the piece is out of bounds
        #if piece will be out bounds when place rotate to see if that helps
        if((( piece.w + position[0] ) > len( self.state )) or (( piece.l + position[1] )> len( self.state[0] ))):
            piece.rotate()
            
        if((( piece.w + position[0] ) > len( self.state )) or (( piece.l + position[1] )> len( self.state[0] ))):
            return False
        #TODO: Check if piece can be placed without intersecting another placed piece
        

        return True

    # Input: piece - PuzzlePiece object
    # Insert piece into the next available position on the board and update state
    def place(self, piece):
        # TODO: Bug in this function. Pieces not being placed correctly.
        position = self.__next()
        if self.fits(piece):
            for i in range(position[0], position[0] + piece.w ):
                for j in range(position[1], position[1] + piece.l):
                    if((( piece.w + position[0] ) > len( self.state )) or (( piece.l + position[1] )> len( self.state[0] ))):
                        return
                    if(self.state[i][j]== 0):
                        #self.used_piece.append(piece)
                        self.state[i][j] = piece.id
                    else:
                        continue
            return position

    def check(self, piece):
        position = self.__next()
        if(position[0] + piece.w > self.w or position[1] + piece.l > self.l):
            return False
        return True

    # Returns whether the board has been filledwith pieces
    def completed(self):
        return True if not self.__next() else False

    def copy(self):
        copied = PuzzleBoard(self.l, self.w)
        copied.state = copy.deepcopy(self.state)
        return copied

class PuzzlePiece():

    def __init__(self, pid, length, width):
        self.id = pid
        self.l = length
        self.w = width
        itfits = False

    def rotate(self):
        #TODO: Bug in this function. Pieces are not rotating correctly
        temp = self.l
        self.l = self.w
        self.w = temp

    def orientation(self):
        return "H" if self.w >= self.l else "V"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"ID: {self.id}, LENGTH: {self.l}, WIDTH: {self.w}, ROTATED: {self.rotated}"

def parse_input(filepath) :

    #TODO: Bug in this function. Error raised when called
    parsed = {'board' : {}, 'pieces' : {}}
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        file_contents = f.read().strip().split("\n")
        board_length, board_width = file_contents[0].strip().split(",")
        parsed['board']['length'] = int(board_length)
        parsed['board']['width'] = int(board_width)
        for i in range(1, len(file_contents)):
            #FIX: the issue was fix
            pid, l, w = file_contents[i].strip().split(",")
            pid, l, w = int(pid), int(l), int(w)
            parsed['pieces'][pid] = {}
            parsed['pieces'][pid]['length'] = l
            parsed['pieces'][pid]['width'] = w
    return parsed

def helper(board, piece):
    unused = []
    #for piece in pieces:
    if board.fits(piece):
        position = board.place(piece)
        board.used_piece.append((piece, position))

    return board





def solve(board, remaining, used_pieces=[]):
    # TODO: Implement a solution for a variable amount of pieces and puzzle board size.
    # HINT: Recursion might help.7
    poss = queue.Queue()
    poss.put(board)

    currboard = PuzzleBoard(len(board.state), len(board.state[0]))
    while not currboard.completed():
        currboard = poss.get()
        #print(currboard.state)
        for piece in remaining:
            fakeboard = copy.deepcopy(currboard)
            if(not (piece.id in np.array(fakeboard.state))):
                #if( fakeboard.check(piece)):
                poss.put(helper(fakeboard, piece))

    print("Suff done")
    return currboard

        
    


    '''if(len(remaining) != 0):
        board, used_pieces, unused_pieces = helper(board, remaining, used_pieces)
        if board.completed():
            return board, used_pieces
        for i in board.state:
            print(i)
        print("\n \n")
        return solve(board, unused_pieces, used_pieces)
    return board'''

def main():
    #TODO: Bug in this function. Positions are not correct after solution is found.
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('input')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    parsed = parse_input(args.input)
    board = PuzzleBoard(parsed['board']['length'], parsed['board']['width'])
    pieces = []
    for k, v in parsed['pieces'].items():
        pieces.append(PuzzlePiece(k, v['length'], v['width']))
    solved = solve(board, pieces)
    if not solved:
        print("No solution found for given input.")
    else:
        print("Solution found.")
        board = solved
        for u, position in solved.used_piece:
            print(f"Piece ID: {u.id}, Position:{position}, Orientation: {u.orientation()}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: There does not appear to be a direct question. You might have better luck over on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. :-)

Comment: It taking forever to come up with a solution so I just want to know if there is anything I can do to fix it.

Comment: In your input file the puzzle is 10x10, but the 5th piece is 20x2? further if you sum the area of all the pieces it should give 100 (10x10)?

Comment: 1,10,1 = 10 ---    2,1,10 = 10---     3,1,5   =   5---   4,3,5   =   15---   5,20,2 =  40----   6,1,5   = 5---  7,1,5   = 5---   8,2,5   =  10   If you add them up, you get 100.

Comment: You are brute forcing all arrangements, so it will obviously be slow. You need to use some optimisation

Comment: So I can't add, but the 20x2 piece is still not place-able in a 10x10 puzzle.

Comment: Yeah I am asking for help with optimization guys. Not too sure where to start.